# Interpreting some assembly instructions

Tags: assembly

I am trying to solve this [crackme](http://www.crackmes.de/users/monads/facets/). I do not want to check the solution until I have not tried to solve it myself. Unfortunately I can not figure out what is happening here:

```
0x080496e0:  movl   $0xc324148b, 0x804974b
0x080496ea:  call   0x804974b
...
0x0804974b:  jmp    0x080496e0
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, I am curious how could I improve this question in order to be OK for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first instruction (`movl   $0xc324148b, 0x804974b`) writes 4 bytes at the address 0x804974B.
These bytes are in order: 0x8B, 0x14, 0x24, 0xC3.

The first 3 form an instruction: `mov edx, [esp]`
The last also forms an instruction: `ret`

Since the second instruction (`call   0x804974b`)` calls this address, the pair of instructions that were created on the fly get executed.

Comment: And if I intrepret good, the jump instruction is 5 bytes, and the last byte (0x80) will cause an interrupt?

Comment: Any bytes beyond the newly created `ret` won't get executed. The 0x80 will not cause an interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing complex going on here. If you can't understand this, you are probably overthinking it. Try to be as dumb as the machine executing this. Or maybe you struggle with the instructions ? If so, just consult some x86 reference.

```
0x080496e0:  movl   $0xc324148b, 0x804974b
```

This instruction just write the value `0xc324148b` in memory at the address `0x804974b`. In Intel syntax, which I find more intuitive, it would be written `mov dword ptr 0x804974b, 0xc324148b`.

```
0x080496ea:  call   0x804974b
```

This instruction call the function located at address `0x804974b`. It will push a return address, jump to `0x804974b` and execute the code there. You can notice here that this is also the address to which the previous value was written. This means the DWORD was actually some code, and not some data. This is perfectly valid in a Von Neumann architecture like x86 (there might be some problems with read/write/execute properties of the memory, but you can just assume it's set properly here).